# python import of script with argparse

Tags: python, import, argparse

A = a script that is structured to be called by command-line with options that are parsed internally by the python argparse library.
B= another script that should call inside itself functions used in A.

I was believing that doing in B an import of A was what I needed but it returns me the usage options and then exits from python interpreter.

Is there a way to preserve A and import it in B passing to it the args? or should I rewrite a avoiding the parser use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, it's not related to any particular or specified code it's really a general question for an advice.

Comment: You should show what code you have in A and B for people to be able to answer definitely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your script A, check if you are the "main script" before parsing arguments and doing A job, otherwise this will be ran too when you only need to use A as a library.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-k", dest = "foo",  action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # do things...
```

Comment: I call this a "dunder pattern", as there are so many doubled characters. Typically, you have functions and classes in body of given file, and on the bottom you put this `if __name__ ...`, which cals "main" function defined in previous lines. This conditional part just prevents to do what is expected to happen when you run the script as script and not importing it as python module.